# Why isn't my edit contact working?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm displaying a list of Contacts, and have a context menu to Edit Contact by calling an intent. On some contacts it works fine, but on others the Edit Contact activity is blank. Any ideas?

Here is the cursor...

```
 projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID};   
 uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
 cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null,    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
```

Here is the code from my CursorAdapter.getView() ...

```
textView.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)) ;
```

And here is the code from my onContextItemSelected...

```
cursor.moveToPosition(position);
String idContact = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
i.setData(Uri.parse(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI + "/" + idContact));
parent.startActivity(i);
```

I've checked logcat and can see

```
I/ActivityManager(  102): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.EDIT dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/23356 cmp=com.android.htccontacts/.ui.EditContactActivity }
```

but no error messges

Comment: any pattern you noticed with the contacts that dont show up? Didi you try debugging it?

Comment: none I can discern :-( On the emulator I simply added 3 contacts, 2 work, one doesn't.

On a real device, I get nothing whatsoever.

I can't find anything to debug. The code is executing correctly, with no silent exceptions. I can see the intent being fired. After that point, it's up to Android to do the rest. 

My guess is there is something wrong with the CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, or the way I'm deriving the contact ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
long idContact = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
```

then

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, idContact); 
i.setData(contactUri);
```

Comment: Seems to work perfectly. I'll do some more testing and then accept the answer. Many thanks.

Comment: I'm glad I helped. The main problem was `_ID` instead of `CONTACT_ID`. Contacts data are stored in multiple tables and `_ID` is an id in one of those tables.