# Use Android Contacts app to edit a raw contact which was added by a custom ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

My app adds contact '*Bob*' to the address book using a custom `ContentProvider`.
In the Android Contacts app, *Bob* shows up just as any other (Google) contact. But when I edit *Bob* in the Contacts app, the data provided by my application is not editable. So far so good.

**My question is**: From within my app, is there a way to fire up the Contacts app, in a way that allows the user to edit the portion of *Bob* that belongs to my app?

I have tried to use the corresponding `Intent`, as described in this [Android guide](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/modify-data.html), but using the **raw** contact uri for *Bob*:

```
Uri rawUri = getRawContactUri("Bob");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT, rawUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, EDIT_CONTACT_RESULT);
```

which brings up the Contacts app, but still without the possibility to edit *Bob*'s data.

There are plenty of questions on SO covering how to [open your app from within the Contacts app when a custom field is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490105/perform-some-action-with-custom-field-of-contact) or [how to fire `ACTION_EDIT` correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439336/why-isnt-my-edit-contact-working).
But I did not find any statement - including a reference - if it is possible to use Contacts app to let the user edit custom raw contacts. Does anyone have a clue and preferably a reference?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add EditSchema to your contact.xml file and add meta-data, pointing to that file in SyncService section of your manifest file, like this:

```
<service
    android:name=".syncadapter.SyncService"
    android:exported="true">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
        android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.provider.CONTACTS_STRUCTURE"
        android:resource="@xml/contacts" />
</service>
```

Here is example of EditSchema in official sources: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.2.2_r1/packages/apps/Contacts/tests/res/xml/test_basic_contacts.xml/